# CONNECT ERROR: Failed to create directory - in magento 1.7 extension

Tags: magento-1.7

I have just started learning Magento 1.7. and trying to install Ultimate_ModuleCreator extension.  But it's throws an error when I tried to install.

I tried to find solution on net but couldn't.

**Error :-**

CONNECT ERROR: Failed to create directory D:/wamp/www/magento_project\downloader.cache\community\Ultimate_ModuleCreator-1.2.0\app/code/community/Ultimate/ModuleCreator/etc/modulecreator/app/code/codepool/Namespace/Module/controllers/Adminhtml/Module/Entity/Catalog/ProductController/IsTree

Help much appreciated
Thank you in advance
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there's an issue with ths particular module on (windows anyway).

I can extract the module find on a Unix based system, but the path of some of the files is too long for windows to handle (windows can only handle 256 characters, depening on the version though).

It generates errors extracting certain files from the archive, which looks to the be issue connect is having too when trying to install the module.

I can replicate the issue on windows, but it works fine with *Nix.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but when I installed another plugin, it installed correctly without any error.  But there is another problem... When I try to upload ay images in products, it generates an error - Upload HTTP Error.  I applied folder permissions as you said but still unable to upload images (The file size which is I am trying to upload is 6.4 kb and I am using windows OS)... again thank you

Comment: that definitely sounds like a permission problem. What kind of server setup are you using? OS/WebServer etc. Never mind I can see the path WAMP on windows

Comment: It could be possible the path is too long for windows to handle..?

Comment: The path looks strange, try manually installing the modules from here: http://freegento.com/magento-extensions/Ultimate_ModuleCreator-1.2.0.tgz

Comment: It's worked with extension !!! thank you very very much.... 
I am using Windows OS and WAMP 2.0.

Comment: The problem with the long path like this, is only issue of Windows OS or it happens with other OS too ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24824/discussion-between-alpesh-trivedi-and-andrew)